# Is there any way to change datatype in teradata?

Tags: teradata

I want to change the `INTEGEr` field in my table to `VARCHAR`.
How can I do this?

Do I have to create a new table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to create a new table, there's no way to change the datatype from numeric to VarChar.

Simply create a new table and Insert/Select the existing data using *CAST(existingCol AS VARCHAR(xx))*

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE $table_name DROP $column_name;
ALTER TABLE $table_name ADD $column_name varchar(1);
```

Comment: Ahem, this will replace the existing data with NULL, I don't think this is expected :-)

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
-- Adding a new column
ALTER TABLE SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME ADD COLUMN_TEMP VARCHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET 
UNICODE NOT CASESPECIFIC COMPRESS

-- Copying data from the existing column to the new column
UPDATE SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN_TEMP = COLUMN_NAME

-- Dropping the old column
ALTER TABLE SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME DROP COLUMN_NAME

-- Renaming the new column to the old column's name
ALTER TABLE SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME RENAME COLUMN_TEMP TO COLUMN_NAME
```